# Как по файлу без расширения узнать - архив это или нет?

Tags: c#, xml, zip

Есть файлы xml и ZIP, в ZIP тоже есть xml файлы. После обработки документов расширение ZIP и XML меняется на x2p. Можно как-то программно определить какой из файлов ZIP, а какой XML именно после измененного расширения? т.е. temp.x2p - это ZIP или XML? спасибо

Answer (score 6):

Есть другой способ. Обычно файлы имеют свои уникальные сигнатуры (как правило от 2 до 4 первых байтов).

Для ZIP это `0x50 0x4B 0x03 0x04` - то есть надо прочитать 4 первых байта и сверить их, если провал - это точно не ZIP.

Более подробно [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

**Update**

C xml не так все просто - зависит от текстовой кодировки файла. Если текст в кодировке Unicode, то вначале будет стоять сигнатура - [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Скорее всего вы знаете кодировку текста, соответственно надо читать как текст с нужной кодировкой и ловить `<?xml`

Answer (score 2):

[`XDocument.Parse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse?view=netframework-4.8) натравить на файлы.

ZIP- это бинарник и метод сразу же упадет с ошибкой.

Ну а если файл большой, то [`XmlReader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=netframework-4.8) в помощь, который должен упасть на невалидном формате.

Comment: А если там действительно xml, причём большой - сотни мегабайт - то парсинг займёт много времени и памяти. Неэффективно.

Comment: Так то да, но автор не уточнил, это. Можно попробовать через xml reader открыть. Он не все в память грузит и скорее всего упадёт тоже